# What type of screws should I use to attach a sign to fiber cement siding?

Tags: screws, exterior, siding

My house has fiber cement siding and I want to attach a decorative sign to the siding. I'm told that I need a carbide tip drill bit to make a clean cut. But what type of screws should I use? And what length is recommended? (the house is wood framed).

Comment: I just mounted some objects to my house which is sided with Hardie Board (which is probably the same or similar product). I drilled through easily with a cheap Harbor Freight drill bit with no issues. I did screw through the siding into stud for security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use ordinary wood screws.

Beneath the siding should be 3/8" or 1/2" sheathing. That is what the screws will really bite into.

Just make sure your screws are long enough to go through the sign and siding and have at least 1/2 of length beyond that. If you're concerned about water penetration squirt a little bit of caulk in the hole before placing the screw, but doing nothing is probably fine too

Comment: There's no indication of how big/heavy the sign is, but I'd suggest that the OP try to find studs, just to be sure. That also helps ensure that the screws holding the sign up don't accidentally hit wiring or plumbing behind the siding.